# React: Is useEffect not guaranteed to run before the component renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to update some components in `Gatsby.js`, based on what url path I am on.

I am using `useEffect()` to make sure the components only update when `location.pathname` (the part of the url after the domain) changes.

**Here is the code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsbystarterdefault-290qv

For some reason, `useEffect` is not using the updated values of the `location` prop (which is passed to the `header` component, which in turn wraps every page).

To reproduce, go to the *CodeSandbox* above and:

1. Click to page 2, then back again to page 1
2. See console statements that `isHome when re-rendering Header` is `true` while, `isHome at NavItemLink` is `false`

Any idea why `useEffect` does not get the latest value of `location`?

Comment: I think it has to do with rendering JSX within your `useEffect`. Not sure that's the proper approach to doing this.

Comment: [As mentioned in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), `useEffect` runs *after* render, not before.

Comment: I think @AlliterativeAlice gave a good answer to your question. I've also forked your sandbox and provide an alternative approach to rendering your navlinks which uses state to determine the set of navlinks to render: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsbystarterdefault-v2p5w

Comment: Thank you, @RobertCooper . Couple of comments: 1) The other pages don't see get the links in the header, due to the extra `isHome` if-statement you placed in `renderNavLinks`. 2) Hmmm, the `renderNavLinks` code somehow disappeared from the codesandbox you made, so now I cannot remember my second comment..

Comment: @Magnus whoops, I've added back the `renderNavLinks` code. It should all work correctly now. The `isHome` ternary is just rendering out `<a>` elements if you're on the home and then `<Link>` elements if you're not (same logic as you had implemented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommand using useMemo instead of useEffect or storing it inside state. useMemo will compute NavLinks only when it's dependency will change.

```
const generateNavLinks = path => nav.map((navItem, index) => (
  <NavItemLink
    key={navItem.name}
    name={navItem.name}
    to={navItem.path}
    isHome={path === withPrefix("/")}
  />
));

const navLinks = useMemo(() => generateNavLinks(location.pathname), [location.pathname]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you place `geneateNavLinks` **outside** the `Header` component function, and the `navLinks` function **within** the `Header` component function?

Comment: outside header as it's not dependent on any of your props now. only path is needed which we are passing it as argument.

Comment: Works perfectly. Do you have any tips/resources on how to know when to use `useEffect` vs `useMemo`?

Comment: This is really good blog post about how to write resilient component by Dan: https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [React documentation on useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), `useEffect` is "similar to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`". Meaning yes, it runs only after the component renders.

You need to rerender the header component after changing `navLinks`. I recommend you do this by making `navLinks` part of the component state with the `useState` hook:

```
const [navLinks, setNavLinks] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    setNavLinks(
        nav.map((navItem, index) => (
            <NavItemLink
              key={navItem.name}
              name={navItem.name}
              to={navItem.path}
              isHome={location.pathname === withPrefix("/")}
            />
        ))
    )
}, [location.pathname])
```

I've created a fork of your code sandbox with the header component updated to use the `useState` hook like shown above: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsbystarterdefault-ftogs

Comment: why does he need to put component in state. i think react will take care of updating props if he just put in returned jsx.

Comment: @eramit2010 He specified that he wants to recreate the NavItemLink components only when `location.pathname` changes, not every time the header component renders.

Comment: Thank you. Is it a typical pattern that `useEffect` changes the component's `state`, to enforce a re-render? Regarding the discussion above, I am not sure I fully follow, but yes the point of `useEffect` was to ensure the `navlinks` are *only* updated when `location.pathname` changes (not on every re-render, which happens too often).

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice in that case he can use useMemo. storing in state will increase one render cycle.